# Why it is showing socket closed even though it was working well

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I had created a order book from luno api and it was working well but suddenly it has stopped working? It is showing "retrying... Socket Closed ".
Someone told me maybe it is because of their api has changed, but I don't understand.

Here is the docs where I got web socket api [Luno API docs](https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#tag/Streaming-API)

```
created() {
  this.connect("wss://ws.luno.com/XBTZAR")
},
```

Comment: What is `XBTZAR` ? Did you checked if something likely to what you're using was changed here? https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#tag/Changelog Otherwise, check if your Git do have some changes. Maybe an API key expired? Or somebody messed-up with the dashboard of your Luno account?

Comment: XBT is for Bitcoin and ZAR is for South African Rand. So basically, it returns bitcoin in South African Rand.